# In os of 5.x.I can not set the bounds of view so that the image fit it

Tags: ios, uiview

`MTDealAnnotationView *view = (MTDealAnnotationView *)[_mapView viewForAnnotation:an];
        view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, iconWidth, iconHeight);
        view.alpha = alph;`

The codes above is what I wrote in my app.

And in this view is an image.

the iconWidth is `17` and the iconHeight is `20`. The size of the image is `30x35`.

I used to got the result that the image in the view its size is `17x20` too.

But now the size of image is `30x35`. But this only happens on devices runs iOS5.x . iOS6 is good.

Any one can tell me what happened?

Comment: Try `view.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Comment: Try setting the `contentMode` of the view.

Comment: MTDealAnnotationView *view = (MTDealAnnotationView *)[_mapView viewForAnnotation:an];
        view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, iconWidth, iconHeight);
        view.alpha = alph;

Comment: The whole code is above. And I tried the ways jjv360 and iMasa told me .But I still can not got the result I want..